# Passing a variable as ngModel to attribute directive

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

#### Say I have the following table row:

```
<tr ng-repeat="item in tableData track by item.id" 
    row-operation-directive="item">
```

#### And the following directive:

```
angular.module('LBTable').directive('rowOperationDirective', function () {
    return{
        restrict: 'A',
        scope:{
            item: '=ngModel'
        },
        link:function (scope, element, attr, ngModel) {

            var i = scope.item;
        }
    }
});
```

Can anyone tell me why this does not work (item in the scope is `undefined`)

Comment: try removing ngModel after =.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just parse your item in an additional param and not in the directive attribute itself. You can't access `$scope` params in the direcitve CDATA itself. In that way it will work like in this **[demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/L47nuvym/)**.

#### View

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <table>
    <tr ng-repeat="item in myData track by item.id" 
        row-operation-directive 
        my-item="item">
      <td>{{ item }}</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

### Directive

```
myApp.directive('rowOperationDirective', function () {
    return{
        restrict: 'A',
        scope:{
            item: '=myItem'
        },
        link:function (scope, element, attr, ngModel) {
            var i = scope.item;
            console.log(i);
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

For this to work you need to change the element to this:

```
<tr ng-repeat="item in tableData track by item.id" row-operation-directive item="item">
```

Change scope to: item: "="